# What's the differences between div#sidebar and #sidebar div?

Tags: css

I just get a bit confused at the concept of **div#sidebar**, I only knew about **#sidebar div**,which means to choose the div element when id = sidebar. 
So what does div#sidebar means? why there is such a method?

Comment: Div#sidebar means select only div element with I'd navbar. Whereas #navbar means select any element with id navbar

Answer (score 1):

`div#sidebar` selects a `div` which has an `id` of `sidebar`.

```
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

`#sidebar div` selects a *parent element* which has an id of `sidebar` (which may have any tag name) and uses the descendant selector (a space) to select descendants of the sidebar which are `<div>`s.

```
<main id="sidebar>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <article>
    <div></div>
  </article>
</main>
```

Above, all the `<div>`s will be targeted.

Comment: Thanks! I guess now I understand it more. The key is whether you want to choose the parent element or not! If you want, you can use div#sidebar,otherwise use #side bar div!

Answer (score 0):

- `div#sidebar` will select `<div id="sidebar">` - Select element with specified ID
- `#sidebar div` will select `<div id="sidebar"><div>` - inner div - Select element that has parent with specified ID

```css
div#sidebar,
#sidebar2 div {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 50%;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar"><div>div#sidebar</div></div>
<div id="sidebar2"><div>#sidebar div</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess the example is quite clear to me. So #sidebar div uses descendants selector, only descentdants element will be chosen. And div#sidebar will choose all the div element named bysidebar and the descentdants will inherit (e.g. the color attribute). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, will apply to descendant `<div>` will have applied this rule (not inherited!). But for example `font-size` will be inherited for all child elements

Comment: Oh yes, background-color can't be inheirted. The default bg-color is trasprent. I use this code and test again, now get it!

Comment: `<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div#sidebar,
#sidebar2 div {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 50%;
}
#cool{
background-color: yellow;
}
div {
 
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 3px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sidebar"><div id="cool">div#sidebar</div></div>
<div id="sidebar2"><div>#sidebar div</div></div>
</body>
</html>`